# Is there a way to set multiple colored text in QPushButton in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

My current QPushButton looks like this;

[image]

but i need a way to make that (3) look in a different color.

current StyleSheet;

```
QPushButton {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,100);
border-style: outset;
border: 2px solid rgb(0,255,0);

}
QPushButton:hover {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,50);
border-style: outset;
border-radius: 30px;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);
border-style: inset;
border-radius: 30px;
}
QPushButton:focus {
color: rgba(255,255,255,255);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,125);
border-style: inset;
border-radius: 30px;
}
```